# How to remove cookies preserved by httr::GET?

Tags: r, httr

`httr::GET` preserves cookies when making requests to the same website.

1. Is it possible to query those preserved cookies?
2. How can I flush those preserved cookies and make "pristine" requests again?

Example:

```r
# Get login cookie
r1 <- GET("https://some.url/login", authenticate("foo", "bar"))

cookies(r1)
# returns a data frame of two cookies

# Make request that requires authentication cookie
# Only succeeds if r1 was made
r2 <- GET("https://some.url/data/?query&subset=1")
r2
```

Notice that when making `r2` you dont have to pass any cookie information explicitely as they are stored somewhere automatically.

I would like to know how these stored cookies can be queried or deleted?

Comment: I'm not sure about clearing existing cookies, but see the example in `?httr::cookies` for querying them.

Comment: Thanks @nrussell `cookies()` is not exactly what I meant. But I have added an example to clarify things.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use a new handle to request.

```
h1 <- handle('')
r1 <- GET("https://some.url/login", handle=h1, authenticate("foo", "bar"))

h2 <- handle('')
r2 <- GET("https://some.url/data/?query&subset=1", handle=h2)
```

Comment: Thanks! That solves (2). Do you have any ideas how to approach (1)?

Comment: Doesn't cookies(r1) return the preserved cookies?

Comment: But are they used when making `r2`? I dont understand how it works.

Comment: When you pass a new handle into the request, it is pristine request. You can call `cookies(r1)` and `cookies(r2)` to see what cookies are stored.

Answer (score 0):

One (very round about) way is to "reset" the package:

```
detach("package:httr", unload=TRUE)
library(httr)
```

I'm still looking for something better.

Comment: yeah... that's pretty blunt. Problematic too if you need to have other packages depending on `httr` loaded.

Comment: I'd be interested to see if you come up with something, I'm still trying to figure something out for myself... I tried looking at the global settings httr has but no luck so far

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
# Get login cookie
r1 <- GET("https://some.url/login", authenticate("foo", "bar"))

cookies(r1)
# The cookies should be there, then:
handle_reset("https://some.url")
cookies(r1)
#now the cookies should be removed
```

I hope it helps